# Is there any diplomatic or strategic hurdle from Russian part regarding arms sales to Pakistan?

Tags: russian-federation, pakistan

Monetary matters aside, can Pakistan buy, say, 100 units of [Su-30MK](http://www.uacrussia.ru/en/aircraft/lineup/military/su-30mk/)/[Su-30SM](http://www.uacrussia.ru/en/aircraft/lineup/military/su-30sm/)/[Su-35](http://www.uacrussia.ru/en/aircraft/lineup/military/su-35/)s from Russia? What about [S400 SAM](http://www.raspletin.com/zrs-s-400-triumf) systems?

Given the present circumstances, Is there any diplomatic or strategic hurdle from Russian part which is able to block the sale of highly advanced Russian arms to Pakistan? If yes, what are they?

Comment: The SU-33 would be a slightly surprising purchase, given that it's designed to be carrier based and it doesn't appear that there are any plans to obtain or build the carriers to put them on.

Comment: @origimbo, kindly correct your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Do you ask specifically regarding these weapon systems?

[Russia did sell Mi-17 helicopters to Pakistan](http://www.thehindu.com/news/international/russian-firm-delivers-mi171e-convertible-helicopter-to-pak/article19336429.ece) and also [sold Mi-35 helicopters](http://thediplomat.com/2017/08/pakistan-receives-4-advanced-attack-helicopters-from-russia/), so there doesn't seem to be any blockade regarding arms sale to Pakistan from Russia.

[This article](http://thediplomat.com/2017/02/will-pakistan-buy-russias-s-400-missile-air-defense-system/) mentions lifting of an arms embargo in 2014 and Pakistan contemplating possibility of purchases including S-400s.

Comment: `Do you ask specifically regarding these weapon systems?` -- Yes. Those are advanced and high-profile weapon systems.

Comment: From these quoted sources it would seem there is no such hurdle. Only issue would be diplomatic viz US, India, and also Russian worry of reverse engineering by Chinese (http://nationalinterest.org/feature/china-stole-fighter-russia%E2%80%94-its-coming-the-south-china-sea-17087) given close Sino-Pak relations.